# Undefined reference error in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I am having an issue with my makefile

```
assignment3: BSTapp.cpp BST.o
        g++ -o assignment3 BSTapp.cpp BST.o
BST.o:  BST.cpp BST.h Node.o
    g++ -c BST.cpp -o BST.o
Node.o: Node.h Node.cpp
    g++ -c Node.cpp -o Node.o
```

getting an undefined reference to all methods in the Node class. But if I directly compile using

```
g++ -o assignment3 BSTapp.cpp BST.h BST.cpp Node.h Node.cpp
```

everything works fine. What am I doing wrong in the makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you left out the `Node.o` file from the makefile command under the `assignment3:` rule:

```
g++ -o assignment3 BSTapp.cpp BST.o
```

should be

```
g++ -o assignment3 BSTapp.cpp BST.o Node.o
```

Remarks:

I. **Please don't compile headers themselves!**

```
g++ -o assignment3 BSTapp.cpp BST.h BST.cpp Node.h Node.cpp
```

should be

```
g++ -o assignment3 BSTapp.cpp BST.cpp Node.cpp
```

II. Your Makefile is extremely unorganized. Better do this:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))

all: assignment3

assignment3: $(OBJECTS)
        g++ -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
        g++ -c -Wall -o $@ $<
```

Comment: If I add Node.o at the end, I get a 'Node.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized'?

Comment: @AbhishekIyer Well, that's strange.

Comment: even with your version of the makefile, I am getting the same error. On a mac I am getting 'ignoring file Node.o, file was built was unsupported file format'

Comment: You should delete Node.o and let make recompile it for you.  It likely was built incorrectly so it's not a standard object file, but as long as the time-last-modified is newer than the source files it won't be rebuilt.

Comment: cool. That fixed that issue, but now I am getting "Node.o: linker input file unused because linking not done."